# Google Drive SDK: Next step after obtaining a token from generateAssertion()

Tags: php, google-drive-api, service-accounts

Alright, I'm trying to set my application up with with the Google Drive SDK. I am using it as a service account, so the set up is a little different. This is how I am doing things:

including required files:

```
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/auth/Google_AssertionCredentials.php';
require_once "google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php";
```

define constants:

```
DEFINE("TRUE_PATH",$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'path/to/file');
DEFINE("SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL","somecode@developer.gserviceaccount.com");
DEFINE("DRIVE_SCOPE","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive");
```

the function:

```
function generateAssertion() {

    $assertionCredentials = new Google_AssertionCredentials();

    $assertionCredentials->serviceAccountName='somecode@developer.gserviceaccount.com';

    $assertionCredentials->privateKey=
    TRUE_PATH.'9e01fd1414aa082fadeec316161eb7028558fbde-privatekey.p12';

    $assertionCredentials->privateKeyPassword = 'notasecret';
    $p12cert = array();
    $file = TRUE_PATH.'9e01fd1414aa082fadeec316161eb7028558fbde-privatekey.p12';
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        try {
            $assertion = $assertionCredentials->generateAssertion();
            return $assertion;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            d($assertionCredentials);
            return 'Caught exception: ' . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
        }
    } else {
        return "no p12 privatekey file";
    }
}
```

the line $assertion = $assertionCredentials->generateAssertion(); gives me a code that loooks like this:

eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJodHRwczpcL1wvYWNjb3VudHMuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbVwvb1wvb2F1dGgyXC90b2tlbiIsInNjb3BlIjpudWxsLCJpYXQiOjEzNTMzNjk3NzUsImV4cCI6MTM1MzM3MzM3NSwiaXNzIjoiMjY5Mjg1NDU2NjY0QGRldmVsb3Blci5nc2VydmljZWFjY291bnQuY29tIn0.KMBTsGZkhLhddBFtc0PB1qZgtdQYyirhWtYixCYx1zo5Otv9pCUBfvrCXOg3JzR-mzE6zHuCZdmGOD7w_LRwYHJpoo0rdpxDXLjtNCgFZdu1d21cVAnqTkIhMGvdS_K7JP_KioXyi-nBdvZt9IXKaApIdDKhRp-T5HByIeO2ijU

my question is, what do I do with the code/token returned from generateAssertion() so that I can access my drive account?
I tried using it as an access token and a refresh token with no success.

I apologize if this is a stupid question, but I am new to the sdk
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!!!

Comment: That's all documented here by the way: https://developers.google.com/drive/service-accounts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call generateAssertion(). Rather, just give the credentials to the client instance and let it do the work of generating the assertion

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAssertionCredentials($assertionCredentials);
```

See http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/OAuth2 for additional details.